# Tossing around some contest ideas

Tags: discussion, community-event, promotion

With the recent success of [**Gaming's**](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/) [**contests**](http://me3missions.com/), it got me thinking about our potential as a site to run similar contests.  I would like to get an idea from the community about my ideas for contests and rewards for said contests.  Obviously, these would have to wait until we graduate from beta and have a much larger user base so these are a bit off and keep that mind when discussing these ideas.  Again,

---

### **These ideas are my own and do NOT represent any ideas of the SE team of employees, CHAOS, and whoever else is affiliated with Stack Exchange, these are just my ramblings for contest ideas.**

---

Because of the nature of SE sites (Q&A) the only reliable way to do a contest is by tracking it by a specific tag.  For a recent example, we could do a question for **The Avengers**.  Anyone with the best combined vote score in Questions and Answers in any movie in The Avengers series including: [iron-man](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man), [iron-man-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man-2), [incredible-hulk-2008](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incredible-hulk-2008), [thor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor), [captain-america](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america), or [avengers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers).  These Q&A's would have be from when the contest started to give everyone an even ground.  The prizes could include every movie in the series on DVD or Blu-Ray or maybe some kind of collector item relating to the series, etc (obviously the prizes would probably have to depend on what SE could give us a budget for).

---

Another example could be, instead of a series, a director's line of work like [christopher-nolan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-nolan) or [steven-spielberg](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steven-spielberg) and the same concept as above, with the winner getting  say, up to 5 of the movies from that director's catalog.

---

The first example would be the purpose of riding along a popular movie's release like The Avengers, while the second example could be a director/series of the week contest or just, again, ride along a director's latest release's popularity.

Obviously, all these details would have to be hammered out between us and the SE team but for the moment, I wanted to garner some ideas and reactions to these kinds of contests on our site once we reach a certain popularity (probably *after* graduation from beta).  The success of these contests for gaming has been *staggering* to the point where they are as huge as the original trilogy of SE sites.  This is a goal I know we can accomplish in the future.

As stated, I wanted to see how the community would want to formulate these kind of things or if anyone has any ideas on different contest or prizes that you would like to see (within reason of course).

As always, we can always promote the site by tweeting and sharing questions, showing friends, and just general participation on the site.

Comment: that could be pretty cool

Comment: As with any of the contests, some care should be shown in trying not to overlap - I'm fairly sure Scifi has something planned for **The Avengers** as well.

Comment: @IanPugsley Of course.  I wasn't even aware of that, though it makes sense.

Comment: The Hunger Games would be a pretty awesome one to do, but it's opening **this week**

Comment: @DForck42 that is a good point.  Giving out books possibly for adaptations.  There are 2 more books to do ya know ;)

Comment: I just meant it'd be an awesome movie to cover because of all the buzz around it, but yeah giving out books for adaptations (if the winner so chooses?) would be cool

Comment: It all depends on what we show enthusiasm for and what *we* commit to it.  If the site commits well to a contest, I assume SE has no problem backing it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, Scifi has http://avx.stackshowdown.com/

What you need is a movie with more content and story than fluff to pass the gates. Originally I thought of MIB but the content relies too much on Sci-fi.

I suggest The Bourne Legacy and all previous Bourne movies

The format should be as a map, placing users on the map based on what scene their question is about. This is just eye candy for now until I could figure out some sort of travelling achievement prize.

The levels should be based on the entire story line

Examples

- Lost asset
- Obtaining identifcation
- Asset clash (fights)
- Spy information retrieval

And so on, this could get really complex or not depending on how you look at it but I think the Bourne series has enough meat to get the creative juices flowing. I also believe we need way more time than scifi or gaming to push promotion, the site is not going to magically get  more visitors because we have a contest and we cannot leave the promotion all to Chaos. So August 3rd as the movie launch date sounds good.

*An idea can be to have a network of assets (with movies SE wear) promoting Bourne and Movie.SE competition and they are placed on the map as well for users to see*

Chaos has NY, other places would be SF, FL and maybe some in Europe (Really wishful thinking here)

Prizes can be

- Limited edition Bourne DVDs
- Autographs from stars (tricky, if not impossible)
- Pre screening tickets
- Regular coupon tickets
- Books from Robert Ludlum
- (Grand Prize) LG 42LK450 42-Inch 1080p 60 Hz LCD HDTV (taken from gaming)

Comment: I really love this idea, definitely outside of the box.  The reason I depend on CHAOS a bit is for the funding and not much else.  I depend on community for ideas that differ from my generic *ask the best stuff for a prize* and this is exactly that!  Well thought!