# How can we encourage more questions for brand-new movies?

Tags: discussion, promotion

I noticed that many questions asked on this page are about more complex aspects of "older" movies like Inception. I think this is great and analysing these movies is one of the reasons why I love this site.

On the other hand however there are only a handful questions regarding current cinema blockbusters and newly released titles like The Hunger Games, Iron Sky or The Grey for example.

I believe however that these are exactly the topics that would attract a lot of search engine traffic and help us get more people on the site. You google the new movie you just saw in the cinema, you end up here and you start browsing other interesting questions. And **BAM**, you are hooked!

Just look at my question about [Titanic 3D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/are-there-any-differences-between-the-new-and-old-titanic-version-besides-3d), it got more than 800 views in 4 days which is ridiculously high compared to the usual view/day ratio of questions here.

So my question is: What can we actively do to encourage more questions about freshly released movies?

Gaming.SE had an interesting approach to the problem with the promotional grant, where they gave out new games as a gift and in return the users have to ask a bunch of question about the new game. I could imagine a similiar incentive in the form of cinema vouchers, but I am not sure how practical this would be and probably this is out of the question while being in beta anyway.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It is a good question.  Its not entirely clear cut that discussions on recent movies will generate a lot of new traffic.  The Hunger Games has been massively successful, but one recent question has only 112 views.  Your question probably reflected what a lot of people were thinking - what is the difference apart from the 3D?  Anyway, we have discussed tie-ins into upcoming movies, such as The Avengers or Prometheus, but as a beta site we have not got a lot further than talk.  It is good to discuss how to advertise the site though.

Comment: Inception isn't an old movie, it's only 2 years old and still rather relevent.

Comment: Old in the sense of »not currently released and therefore not a google trend«. Notice the ““ above ;)

Answer (score 3):

[As I have expressed before](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/tossing-around-some-contest-ideas), I believe a contest could drive our view count to ridiculous levels.  But as @iandotkelly said, we're in beta which means we get a bit less pull.  Not to mention thinking about it a bit, a contest is actually counter-productive to a beta site's success because the point of beta is to see how well a site can do on their user-base/content alone without a 'crutch' of a contest.

That being said, the only other way we can get the word out is by using all the share links on your own Q/A's, letting your friends know about the site, see the newer movies and ask questions about them (I have been constantly begging the team to give the Mods free movie tickets for the year, but to no avail :p).

When *Avengers* comes out, expect a lot of questions from the community,  *Prometheus*; @iandotkelly might finally ask *something*, and when *Dark Knight Rises* comes out expect, me to go on a bit of a craze about it.

And I'm sure we won't be the only ones very eager to get our questions answered.  The more we get our name out there by tweeting **good** Q/A's, the better the site will do.  Just in the past week alone we went from a 2.4 Q's/Day to 4.6, 88% answered to 90%.

**We are improving**, and now it's up to you guys to *continue* this improvement. :)

Comment: You talking to me?

Comment: That'd be awesome to get free tickets for a year.  I'd watch **everything** just so I could ask questions on here.

Comment: I think movies.stackexchange require promotions such as facebook group/page etc too